# SQL DB2 calculate mode

Tags: sql, db2, subquery

I'm using DB2 and have two tables:

Users:

- ID - key
- Education(integer value represents level)
- Age

Payments:

- Shop
- Sum
- ID - foreign key

I want to calculate statistical mode of education for every shop, for now I'm trying something like that:
1) Calculate mode for shop X:

```
select u.education            
   from users u, payments p
   where u.id = p.id AND              
   p.shop = 'X'       
   group by u.education order by count(*) desc
   fetch first 1 rows only;
```

This query works fine

2) Calculate mode of education for every shop:

```
select p.Shop as Shop,                    
   avg(u.age) as AvgAge,                                    
   (select u1.education                                           
      from users u1                                    
      where u1.id = p.id                                   
      group by u1.education                                        
      order by count(*) desc                                         
      fetch first 1 rows only) as ModeEdu                            
  from users u, payments p                    
  where u.id = p.id                                      
  group by p.Shop;
```

This query gives a error:

SQLCODE = -119, ERROR:  A COLUMN OR EXPRESSION IDENTIFIED IN A HAVING 
CLAUSE IS NOT VALID

Comment: why is avg age included in the query? can you show some sample data and the expected output?

Comment: @vkp I included age because I'm also trying to get some other information about users, but have problem with selecting mode of education.

Comment: @vkp what samples you exactly want to see?

Comment: sample data from the tables and the expected result for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.  I've changed to "modern" joins syntax.  The syntax you were using was "old" 20 years ago.  I **strongly** recommend using the new syntax.

```
WITH eduCount AS
(
   select u1.id, u1.education, count(*) as c
   from users u1
   group by u1.id u1.education                                        
), byUser AS
( 
   select id, education, c,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, education ORDER BY c DESC) AS RN
   from eduCount
)
select p.Shop as Shop,                    
   avg(u.age) as AvgAge,                                    
   max(byUser.education) as ModeEdu
from users u
join payments p on u.id = p.id
left join byUser on byUser.id = u1.id AND rn = 1
group by p.Shop;
```

Comment: I'm using vista tn3270 and spufi to run query, it gives me error:  SQLCODE = -104, ERROR:  ILLEGAL SYMBOL "ROW_NUMBER". SOME SYMBOLS THAT
MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: , FROM INTO

Comment: @MRMKR -- I had a typo

Comment: now I have trouble with group by in eduCount,                     WITH eduCount AS ( select u1.id, u1.education, count(*) as c from users u1 group by u1.id, u1.education )                                                         giving an error: U1.ID IS NOT VALID IN THE CONTEXT WHERE IT IS USED

Comment: you list ID as a column in users.  Did you copy the typo I had and have `us.ID` in the group by clause?

Comment: I corrected all typos, but now problem is that I have maximum education value from customers in shop. I mean: shop 'Planes' have customers with 2,3,4 education level, and there 2000 people with level 2, 1000 with 3, and 500 with 4. Result should be 2, but query gives 4. I tried to delete max function, but it gives now results for every education level.

Comment: @MRMKR  hmmm not sure -- but maybe `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY c DESC) AS RN` will fix it.  It is hard to do in my head without seeing the results of each query.   What you are asking for might not make sense (since the prior query is counting by education too)  but try that change.

Comment: Not working after change ROW_NUMBER(), maybe there are some other way ?

Comment: @MRMKR -- maybe, but I'd have to see the sample data and expected results -- I can't do it in my head right now.

Comment: I solved the problem, thanks for the answer! Really appreciate it.